# How / Why are global variables available/in scope in nested class instances but "nonlocal" variables are not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, nested

How to access `OuterClass` variables in a similar manner to how global variables are accessed?

For example:

```
global_variable = 'global_variable'

class InnerClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        return super().variable

    def test_global(self):
        return global_variable


class OuterClass:

    def __init__(self, inner_class_instance):
        self.variable = 'class_variable'
        self.inner_class_instance = inner_class_instance
```

Running the below returns the global variable:

```
inner = InnerClass()
outer = OuterClass(inner)
outer.inner_class_instance.test_global()
```

However trying to access the `nonlocal` class variable results in an `AttributeError`:

```
outer.inner_class_instance.test()
```

`super()` is incorrectly used in `InnerClass.test` as `OuterClass` is not a base class for `InnerClass`. How to access `OuterClass` variables in a similar manner to how global variables are accessed? That is without passing a context argument to `InnerClass`. Using `nonlocal variable` in `InnerClass.test` resulted in a `SyntaxError`.

Also, how and why are the global variable accessible from `InnerClass.test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not generally possible for an instance that is assigned as an attribute of some other instance to get a reference to the containing instance. For one thing, there may be zero or more than one such references! For example, if you created a second instance of `OuterClass` with the same `InnerClass` instance, there would be two potentially different `variable` attributes that you might want to read.

In general, if you want to access a object's attributes you need a reference to the object first. It having a reference to you is not enough, unless you arrange some alternative API.

For instance, maybe the `InnerClass` expects to get a reference to `OuterClass` in its `test` method, and `OuterClass` gets a method to pass itself in:

```
class InnerClass:
    def test(self, outer):
        return outer.variable

class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, inner, variable):
        self.inner = inner
        self.variable = variable

    def run_test(self):
        return self.inner.test(self)

out = OuterClass(InnerClass(), "foo")
print(out.run_test())
```

You could also have your classes set up circular references, where they each reference each other. Then either one could do stuff with the other:

```
class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outer = None

    def test(self):
        if self.outer is None:
            raise ValueError("Not in an OuterClass instance!")
        return self.outer.variable

 class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, inner, variable):
        self.inner = inner
        inner.outer = self      # set reference back to us!
        self.variable = variable

out = OuterClass(InnerClass(), "foo")
print(out.inner.test())
```

This is a very crude version of this sort of approach, you might want to ensure your references remained consistent (preventing the same `InnerClass` instance being used by two different `OuterClass` instance, for example).

Note that circular references like this make the garbage collector's work harder. Normally Python objects get cleaned up immediately after their last reference goes away. But objects with reference cycles always have references going between each other, and so the GC needs to check if the whole set of objects is dead all together. It will probably manage it pretty well for a cycle that contains just two objects like this example, but a in a larger data structure it might be more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In the `test(self)` method of `InnerClass`, you've wrongly understood the meaning of the expression `super().variable`. `super()` here refers to the superclass of `InnerClass`, which (even though not explicit in the code) happens to be the predefined class called `Object`. And the `Object` class certainly doesn't have an attribute called `variable`. And that is why that line throws the error

> 'super' object has no attribute 'variable'

Your other question was -- "How to access `OuterClass` variables?".

I'd like to first clean up some basic aspects of the concepts here.

First of all, that thing you have inside `InnerClass`, having the name `variable`, is actually an **attribute** of `InnerClass`. So I would rather re-phrase your question as "How to access the `OuterClass` **attributes** from within a method of `InnerClass`?".

Second, just because `OuterClass` receives a reference to an instance of `InnerClass` when the `__init__()` method of `OuterClass` executes, doesn't mean that `OuterClass` is in any way "outer to" or "surrounds" `InnerClass`.

From the point of view of the code in `InnerClass`, `OuterClass` is just another class, with no special status -- it is neither a superclass (ancestor class) nor is it an outer class (a surrounding class). Therefore, to access an attribute of an instance of `OuterClass`, from within the `InnerClass` method called `test()`, you first need a name that holds a reference to the `OuterClass` instance. So, for example, within the `test()` method, if you happen to have a name called `my_outer_inst` that holds a reference to an instance of `OuterClass`, you can certainly refer to the `OuterClass` attribute called `variable`, using `my_outer_inst.variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your first question, there is something more to define in the code for `variable`. The `AttributeError` says *`''super' object has no attribute 'variable''`* , means it is not defined inside the class.

Try to execute this, `inner.test()`. You are again getting the same `AttributeError`. Define/Declare `variable` and try it once.

Second question, `global` variables are those that are declared outside the class. They can be accessed anywhere. However, in order to change its value, it has to be declared as `global var_name` inside the class.